# How does TCP identify the application level protocol?

Tags: tcp, websocket

`IP` protocol datagram header contains a `Protocol` field to define the protocol used in the data portion of the IP datagram.

How does a TCP packet identify the its application level protocols? I don't see similar fields in the TCP header format. So it all depends on the `port number`?

If so, does it mean I can silently switch the application protocol on the same port, just like what happens when `WebSocket` uses a handshake request in the format of HTTP to tell the server to switch from HTTP to WebSocket protocol?

Comment: According to here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/1.1_Upgrade_header), it seems the Application Level Protocol switching Over the Same TCP Port does exist.

Comment: And one more ref: The Protocol upgrade mechanism,  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Protocol_upgrade_mechanism

Comment: Both your links are about *HTTP* protocol upgrade mechanisms, not TCP.

Comment: @EJP I add these 2 links just to show that application level protocols can initiate the protocol switch while not changing the underlying TCP port. This is related to the last part of my original question.

Comment: Exactly, so TCP has nothing to do with it, so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP I think there's some relation. I just want to show that TCP doesn't care what the application level protocol is.

Comment: There is no relation. TCP just sends data to the port. The application implements the application protocol(s). You don't appear to understand your own quotations, or indeed your own question.

Comment: @EJP I mean it's related to my question. Anyway, you have the right to express your opinion.

Comment: We aren't talking about opinions. We're trying to establish what you're talking about. You can't ask 'how does TCP identify the application protocol', and then go on to state that 'TCP doesn't care what the application protocol is', without self-contradiction.

Comment: Maybe I should split it into 2 questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP itself does not care about the application layer protocol used. The closest thing is the port number. Port numbers are used to distinguish different connections on the same host. When a packet is received, the operating system uses the port number to determine which program it belongs to. Although many protocols have standard port numbers, you are not required to use them.

So yes, you can switch protocols on the same port.